# single word for 'Hospital' and 'Clinic'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am developing a software that requires users to enter hospital or clinic name. The software treats clinics and hospitals the same way. I wanted to know a *single* word that can be used for any medical institution.

Example use cases:

In forms:

> Hospital/clinic name: ***_*__*_*__*_*____**

In URL:

> http://website.com/hospital/search

While I can use something like "Medical Facility" as blanket term for clinic, hospital, trauma center, nursing home, etc... I do not like it because:

1. it's big.
2. it has two words so URLs wouldn't look great `http://website.com/medical_facility/search`.

Thanks. By the way, 'no' is perfectly OK answer.

Comment: Well I really like **Medical Facility** and cant see your point to make it with one word. After all your goal is to make it understandable for large group of people.

Comment: yeah, we narrowed down to medical facility. It makes hard for savvy audience to directly type-in the page's URL as it contains an underscore (or not). But that will be pretty small group of people. OTOH, we could use `clinic` in url and `Medical Facility` everywhere else, but this conflicts with uniformity -- that an entity will always be referred by one name. Anyway, this is not a big deal. I was just looking for suggestions. Seems there ain't. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "Medical center" is by far the most common phrase I hear used for this (American English speaker) - it sounds more natural than "medical facility" to me.

Comment: On a separate note. If you do decide on a two word solution, use a hyphen in the URL not an underscore: http://www.ecreativeim.com/blog/2011/03/seo-basics-hyphen-or-underscore-for-seo-urls/

Comment: +1 @cowls ha ha, thanks for SEO hint. You see, why I was not liking two words: Was there an underscode, or may be a hyphen or perhaps just glued together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In that case,'no'. :)

If you must use a single word (and I don't see why two words is bad here), I would just use *facility*. In the context of a medical applicaion, it would be just as clear as *medical facility*.

Comment: It's not bad. It's just OK. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 4):

I would just use [Hospital](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hospital):

> Definition of HOSPITAL 
>   1: a charitable institution for the needy, aged, infirm, or young 
>   2: an institution where the sick or injured are
>   given medical or surgical care —usually used in British English
>   without an article after a preposition

It is understandable and I really doubt that your user is going to say "Ah, darn it, they only deal with hospitals and I am looking for a clinic". You could also make it clear that you are using hospital as a blanket word in the text of your web page.

If *hospital* won't serve, perhaps *facility* or *institution* will. Your context seems to make it very clear that you are referring to medical institutions.

Comment: :) yeah, perhaps. May be it's vernacular. But hospital is associated with hospitalized, while a clinic is lighter word. A clinic sounds like a place where one or a small group of doctor/s consult and perhaps, minor treatments are done. I am aware that hospital and clinic can be used interchangeably. I finally decided to use 'medical facility'. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The common English term would be **Health Care Facility** so if you want a single word, just use **Facility**; in context it should be clear that you mean health care facility.

You could also use **site** or **location** if they would be clear in context.